# How do I merge layers using raw pixel data in C# UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, graphics, uwp

Because the Universal Windows Platform does not support flattening Bitmap "layers" by default, I have been creating an algorithm (based on one found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging#create-or-edit-a-softwarebitmap-programmatically)) to take each individual pixels of each layer, and overlay them one over another. The problem is that because I'm using Alpha to allow images to have transparent pixels, I am unsure how to properly merge the pixels so it looks as though one is being places on top of the other.

Here is my code so far:

```
private unsafe SoftwareBitmap CompileImage()
    {
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, Width, Height);

        using (BitmapBuffer buffer = softwareBitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Write))
        {
            using (var reference = buffer.CreateReference())
            {
                byte* dataInBytes;
                uint capacity;
                ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out dataInBytes, out capacity);

                BitmapPlaneDescription bufferLayout = buffer.GetPlaneDescription(0);

                for (int index = 0; index < layers.Length; index++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < bufferLayout.Height; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < bufferLayout.Width; j++)
                        {
                            if(index == 0)
                            {
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 0] =
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 0]; //B
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 1] =
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 1]; //G
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 2] =
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 2]; //R
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 3] =
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 3]; //A
                            }
                            else if(index > 0)
                            {

                                //Attempts to "Average" pixel data
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 0] =
                                    (byte)(dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 0] *
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 0] / 2);
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 1] =
                                    (byte)(dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 1] *
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 1] / 2);
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 2] =
                                    (byte)(dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 2] *
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 2] / 2);
                                dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 3] =
                                    (byte)(dataInBytes[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 3] *
                                    layers[index].pixelData[bufferLayout.StartIndex + bufferLayout.Stride * i + 4 * j + 3] / 2);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return softwareBitmap;
    }
```

The current algorithm will take the average BGRA values of each pixel in every layer, and return the result. This is not what I intended it to do. How do I go about correcting it? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what I'm doing wrong with my posts. Clearly I'm doing SOMETHING wrong if I continue to get so many downvotes despite doing everything the rules suggest I do with my questions -_-

Answer (score 0):

To apply an alpha mix you multiply the previous color by the inverse alpha and the current color by the alpha, of course you should do it on a 0-1 scale (that's why graphic cards work with floats for colors).

Per example, suppose you have three layers, A, B and C, you use A as a base, then mix it with B: (pseudocode)

```
//bAlpha is thge alpha value of the current pixel from B in byte value
var alpha = bAlpha / 255.0f; 
var invAlpha = 1.0f - alpha;

//aRGB is the RGB value of the pixel on the layer A
//bRGB is the RGB value of the pixel on the layer B
var abRGB = aRGB * invAlpha + bRGB * alpha;
```

And now you apply the third layer:

```
//cAlpha is thge alpha value of the current pixel from C in byte value
alpha = cAlpha / 255.0f;
invAlpha = 1.0f - alpha;

//abRGB is the RGB value of the previously mixed layers
//cRGB is the RGB value of the pixel on the layer C
var abcRGB = abRGB * invAlpha + cRGB * alpha;
```

Of course all of this is on ARGB mode, there's also pARGB in which the colors are already premultiplied, so you only need to multiply the previous color by the inverse alpha and add the current color.

```
//bAlpha is the alpha value of the current pixel from B in byte value
var invAlpha = 1.0f - (bAlpha / 255.0f);

//aRGB is the RGB value of the pixel on the layer A
//bRGB is the RGB value of the pixel on the layer B
var abRGB = aRGB * invAlpha + bRGB;

invAlpha = 1.0f - (cAlpha / 255.0f);

//abRGB is the RGB value of the previously mixed layers
//cRGB is the RGB value of the pixel on the layer C
var abcRGB = abRGB * invAlpha + cRGB;
```